# Index data row size not returning actual size?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.overhead ( myID INT NOT NULL ) ;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_overhead -- not unique!
ON dbo.overhead(myID) ;

INSERT  INTO dbo.overhead
        ( myID )
        SELECT  1 ;


SELECT  min_record_size_in_bytes ,
        max_record_size_in_bytes

FROM    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.overhead'),

                                       NULL, NULL, N'SAMPLED') ;



min_record_size_in_bytes   max_record_size_in_bytes

------------------------ ------------------------

25                         25
```

It should give 4 bytes as INT record 1 row is inserted, why 25?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 4 bytes for the record header
- 4 bytes for the int
- 2 bytes for the count of columns in the null-bitmap
- 1 byte for the null bitmap
- 14 bytes versioning tag because you have snapshot isolation enabled (or are using MARS)

That's 25 bytes in total. There are also 2 additional bytes for the slot pointer at the bottom of the page, but those are not accounted for in the DMV.

Source: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/